# MSAccess.SysCmd converting old mdb to accdb, in vb.net vs2019

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I'm having issues converting an old access mdb to the newer format (2007) accdb.
In the past I have used the following code, that works:

```
    ' Delete the resultant accdb just in case
    File.Delete("C:\temp\TheTargetDB.accdb")
    Dim oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    Dim ret = oAccess.SysCmd(603, "C:\temp\TheSourceDB.mdb", "C:\temp\TheTargetDB.accdb")

    oAccess.quit()
    oAccess = Nothing

    If ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox("DID NOT CONVERT")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

However, I've tried using it with variables and this doesn't work:

```
    Dim SourceDBName As String = "C:\temp\TheSourceDB.mdb"
    Dim TargetDBName As String = "C:\temp\TheTargetDB.accdb"

    ' Delete the resultant accdb just in case
    File.Delete(TargetDBName)
    Dim oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    Dim ret = oAccess.SysCmd(603, SourceDBName, TargetDBName)

    oAccess.quit()
    oAccess = Nothing

    If ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox("DID NOT CONVERT")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Is there anything special about the SysCmd that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of pulling my hair out, I stumbled onto the answer while reviewing the Microsoft Doc article: [MS Access SysCmd method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.syscmd)

The argument types for the source and target are the old 'variant' data type.
I decided to modify my code to cast the string variables to the 'Object' type:

Dim ret = oAccess.SysCmd(603, CObj(SourceDBName), CObj(TargetDBName))

vs2019 says the cast is redundant, but guess what? - it worked!

I hope this is useful to anyone in a similar situation.
Cheers
Andrew